# DB2: Procedures comments are not deployed via Data Studio

Tags: db2, comments, procedure

I create a new stored procedure including comments 
etc. /* this is a comment */. But if i have a look at the source tab of this procedure in data studio this line is gone. 
What's going wrong here?

kind regards
Ralf

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider using -- to show comments instead of /* */

The command line (CLP) preserves comments by default with current Db2 versions, i.e. you don't have to use Data Studio for deployment activities.

In Data-Studio, remember to tick the 'Deploy Option' "Deploy source to the database", as by default it is not ticked. In my 4.1.3 version of Data Studio, this preserves comments in SQL procedures.

Losing comments was reported in an old version of Data Studio with a [workaround](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014685000).
The workaround for the issue is to use the Routines Editor to create the stored procedure, then select the DEPLOY button. That will preserve comments.

1. Data Project Explorer
2. Right click on Stored Procedures
3. Select New->Stored Procedure
4. Select any of the templates and click Finish
5. Edit the generated coded and press the DEPLOY button, top right.

If you still have a problem and if your company has an IBM support contract then open a ticket with IBM to get it resolved.